# How to find php version in lithium framework?

Tags: php, upgrade, lithium

I am working on the [Lithium framework](https://li3.me/) to make a PHP application.

I need to upgrade the PHP version and the Lithium framework version but I don't know the current version in the first place.

Where can I find this information within the app directory?

Comment: type `php -v` on cmd line,and the version of the framework looks likes its in [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/2.0/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for the answer. I was able to find out the PHP version but I can't seem to find the Lithium framework version.

Comment: use [`composer show`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#show)